# DependencyProperty is not assigned

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I created an UserControl that exposes a DependencyProperty :

```
namespace MyApp.Sql
{
 public partial class SqlConnectionStringBuilder
 {
    private static readonly SqlConnectionString DefaultValue = new SqlConnectionString { IntegratedSecurity = true, Pooling = false };

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConnectionStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ConnectionString", typeof(SqlConnectionString),
                                    typeof (SqlConnectionStringBuilder),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                        DefaultValue, 
                                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                        ConnectionStringChanged));



    private static void ConnectionStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = (SqlConnectionStringBuilder) d;
        if (e.NewValue == null)
            builder.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => d.SetValue(ConnectionStringProperty, DefaultValue)));
        else
            builder.RegisterNewConnectionString((SqlConnectionString)e.NewValue);
    }

    public SqlConnectionString ConnectionString
    {
        get { return (SqlConnectionString)GetValue(ConnectionStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ConnectionStringProperty, value); }
    }

    private void RegisterNewConnectionString(SqlConnectionString newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != null)
            newValue.PropertyChanged += ConnectionStringPropertyChanged;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Now I try to use the ConnectionString in another UserControl and attach a TextBlock to ConnectionString:

```
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <MyApp.Sql:SqlConnectionStringBuilder  ConnectionString="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=ServerConnectionString}"  />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=ServerConnectionString, StringFormat='Produced Connection String: {0}'}"
               Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

```
namespace MyApp
{
  public partial class SqlProvider
  {
    public SqlProvider
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = this;
    }

    private SqlConnection _connection;
    public SqlConnection ServerConnectionString
    {
        get { return _connection; }
        set
        {
            _connection = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ServerConnectionString");
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
}
```

But the SqlConnectionString is never assigned to the TextBlock. 
When I debug the SqlConnection Property of the ConnectionStringBuilder it always shows null

Where is my fault?

Comment: The 'UserControl' that you are referencing is SqlConnectionStringBuilder, but the class you posted is ConnectionStringBuilder and does not inherit DependencyObject, making the DependencyProperty not valid, doesn't inherit UserControl either

Comment: Sorry this was a copy paste misstake... its name is SqlConnectionStringBuilder and it is a partial of a UserControl.

Comment: Just because it could still be the reason that your code is not working, does your SqlConnectionStringBuilder class inherit UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

Check out your bindings. I assume you're using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder UserControl to create the connection, and in that case, its binding mode should be two way.

Right now, it looks like you're trying to bind to the code-behind of your MainWindow. If you set the UserControl's ConnectionString binding to two way, any changes made to that dependency property will be injected back into the MainWindow's ServerConnectionString property. And, because your MainWindow implements INotifyPropertyChanged, once that ServerConnectionString property is updated, the TextBlock should update.

Also, if you are binding to your MainWindow, it's not necessary to specify the ElementName property in the binding. Since you're setting the `DataContext = this` in the constructor, you could just say `{Binding Path=ServerConnectionString, Mode=TwoWay}` on your UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

If I use ElementNames like this:

```
<MyApp.Sql:SqlConnectionStringBuilder x:Name="sqlConnectionStringBuilder"  ConnectionString="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=ServerConnectionString, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=sqlConnectionStringBuilder, Path=ConnectionString, StringFormat='Produced Connection String: {0}'}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

it works.

But why does Binding to local instance not work?